# Extract XML in a Oracle Database Table Column

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a table 'Users' with column 'Values' in a Oracle database which has XML data like so:

```
<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="first" value="Linda"/>
    <entry key="groups" value="Manager"/>
    <entry key="last" value="Davis"/>
    <entry key="locked" value="N"/>
    <entry key="status" value="A"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>
```

I wish to extract them like:

```
Attributes_Values
=================
first = Linda
groups = Manager
last = Davis
```

I tried ExtractValue function but it returns error saying 'missing right parenthesis'. My query below:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(Values, '/Attributes/Map/entry[@key='first']@value') "Attribute_Values" from 
Users;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL:

```
with t as (
select xmltype('<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="first" value="Linda"/>
    <entry key="groups" value="Manager"/>
    <entry key="last" value="Davis"/>
    <entry key="locked" value="N"/>
    <entry key="status" value="A"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>') xml from dual
)

select dtl.extract('//@key').getStringVal() || ' = ' || dtl.extract('//@value').getStringVal() as "Attributes_Values"
from t s
    ,table(XMLSequence(s.xml.extract('Attributes/Map/entry'))) dtl
```

Result:

```
Attributes_Values
first = Linda
groups = Manager
last = Davis
locked = N
status = A
```

Answer (score 1):

Quotation mark instead of the apostrophe.

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype('<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="first" value="Linda"/>
    <entry key="groups" value="Manager"/>
    <entry key="last" value="Davis"/>
    <entry key="locked" value="N"/>
    <entry key="status" value="A"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>'), '/Attributes/Map/entry[@key="first"]/@value') "Attribute_Values" from dual;
```

Comment: Works fine! Was wondering if we can extract multiple values by passing their relevant key identifiers. E.g. @key="first", @key"last".

Comment: Yes but not with extractvalue. I'thik extractvalue is deprecatd. 

`SELECT * from xmltable( '/Attributes/Map/entry[@key="first" or @key="last" ]/@value' passing xmltype('<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="first" value="Linda"/>
    <entry key="groups" value="Manager"/>
    <entry key="last" value="Davis"/>
    <entry key="locked" value="N"/>
    <entry key="status" value="A"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>') columns value varchar(200) path '.' )`